# Black arch Boot problem, UUID not found

Tags: boot, uuid

I’ve installed black arch “from live iso” and it was installed successfully
But after reboot it stuck in black screen

```
starting version 245.5-2-arch
ERROR: device ‘uuid=xxxxxxxxxx‘ not found skipping fsck. 
mount: /new_root: can’t find UUID=xxxxxxx. 
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell. 
sh: can’t access tty; job control turned off[rootfs ]#
```

By the way I think this picture may help to fix
[image: this appears while installing]

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

check if your `/etc/fstab` has all the partitions that you created, with the corresponding mount points and UUID's.

to get UUID of a drive you can `blkid (drive)`
example `blkid /dev/sda1`

to list all the partitions you can do `lsblk`

Comment: Unlikely to help, since `/etc/fstab` is stored on root (`/`).  Here the instructions for opening the box are inside the box... The instruction of where to find root (`/`) must be stored elsewhere in the either the grub menu entry or the initramfs.

Comment: i guess, you can boot into live usb and `arch-chroot /mnt` and then edit the file? maybe?

Comment: you missed my point.  The boot sequence doesn't use `/etc/fstab` to find `/`.  It can't, because `/etc/fstab` is on `/`.  So the boot sequence must have this one piece of information stored elsewhere.

Comment: im sorry, im no expert. :/

Comment: you can search online for what you just told me. like where does bootsequence stores UUID or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The install script didn't correctly setup which drive to mount as root (`/`).  Maybe something is very broken with your installation maybe it is this one thing.  If it's just this, then you can try to fix it manually...

Most partitions are configured inside `/etc/fstab` but the root partition's information is copied elsewhere.  That's because `/etc/fstab` is stored on root and so this file can't be read until root's been mounted.

Most Linux distributions let you change the root partition during boot by setting the `ROOT=...` kernel parameter:

1. Boot your broken system to the point it drops into the emergency shell.
2. Inside the emergency shell, use the commands `lsblk` and `blkid` to list partitions.  Work out which one is your root partition.  If you followed [the installation guide](https://blackarch.org/blackarch-install.html) this should be `/dev/sda3`.
3. Reboot and when you get to the grub menu, move up / down to "Black Archlinux" and press <kbd>e</kbd>.  This will let you edit the boot entry.
4. Carefully look through to find the line starting `linux`.  It's usually a very long line an may have been wrapped (continued to the next line).  Check this line to see if there is already an option starting `root=`.  If there is then edit it to the partition you found in step 1.  If not then add the option.
5. Boot your system by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>.

---

## Fixing your system once it's booted

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` to correct the entry for `/` if it's wrong.  Even if you didn't use the "UUID" in the steps above, this time you should do so.  You can again use blkid and lsblk to find the partition.
2. Make sure your grub boot entries are up to date by running:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Make sure your initramfs is up to date by running:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -uk all
   ```

Hopefully this should leave you with a fully bootable system.

Comment: Thank you for help.  label not found.  blkid  did not get any result, also when I try to mount boot and root using : mount /dev/sda1 “boot” , mount / dev/sda3 “root” it can’t find in /etc/fstab. 
vi /etc/fstab nothing on it

Comment: [ blackarch / ]# cat /etc/fstab
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# /dev/sda3 UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/dev/sda3            /          ext4       rw,noatime 0 1

# /dev/sda1 UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/dev/sda1            /boot      ext4       rw,noatime 0 2

# /dev/sda2 UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/dev/sda2            none       swap       defaults   0 0

Comment: Root is `/`.  Just above the `/boot` line.  blkid needs to be run as root user (eg: `sudo blkid`). If fstab is empty the you need to populate it.

Comment: @Dr.Eissa It's a little confusing because the error is for `/new_root`.  That's a quirk of the way linux boots up.  `/` can start life as `/new_root` earlier on in the boot sequence.

Comment: `update-initramfs` is a Debianism, I think. The corresponding tool in Arch seems to be `mkinitcpio`. In this case, the command to run instead of `sudo update-initramfs -uk all` would be `sudo mkinitcpio -P`.